# Compile Caffe on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe, nvidia

There is no guide available what-so-ever for how to Compile caffe (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) on macOS high sierra 10.13.x. I have a Macbook pro with GeForce GT 750M.

The latest installation guide I could find is this gist (https://gist.github.com/doctorpangloss/f8463bddce2a91b949639522ea1dcbe4).
Which is also much far from 10.13.1

While following the official documentation I am getting following error while compiling opencv

```
> cd
> /tmp/opencv-20171117-55892-iwynin/opencv-3.3.1/build/modules/datasets
> && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.6/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library
> ../../lib/libopencv_datasets.3.3.1.dylib
> ../../lib/libopencv_datasets.3.3.dylib
> ../../lib/libopencv_datasets.dylib [ 75%] Built target opencv_datasets
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:11:in `raise'
```

Comment: There's a link to [the installation instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) in the read-me in that Github repository. Do you have a more specific issue?

Comment: @You I have tried doing this documentation. Updated the question with error statement